# Convert array of two items into a list and return highest value

Tags: javascript

I have written a function that will recieve an array of two numbers,convert the array into a list, calculate the highest of those two numbers and return this value.

```js
function myFunction(arr) {
  
  // Convert array into a list so we can use Math.max
  var arrList = arr.join();
  
  // Returning the largest item in the list
  var max = Math.max(arrList);
  
  return max;
}

console.log(myFunction([1, 4]));
```

It should return 4. But i get NaN.

Comment: `join` is converting your array into a string

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Math/max => there is an example which shows how to find the max from an array

Comment: Math.max() function returns the largest of zero or more numbers, you are passing a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why it doesn't work?**

Your code doesn't work because [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) returns a string, and [`Math#max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) expects numbers. Because it's a string, the result is [NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) (not a number).

**Solutions**

When you want to take an array, and use it's values as the parameters of a function, you can use [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

The 1st parameter is the `this` to be used in the invoked function, it's not relevant in this case, so I use the original, which is `Math`.

The 2nd param is the array, which will be converted to the function parameters, in this case - the array of numbers.

```js
var arr = [5, 3, 20, 15, 7];

function myFunction(arr) { 
  return Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
}

console.log(myFunction(arr));
```

---

With ES6 you can use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) `...` instead.

```js
var arr = [5, 3, 20, 15, 7];

function myFunction(arr) {
  return Math.max(...arr);
}

console.log(myFunction(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not work, like in source code. You need to use [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) for an array of arguments.

```js
function myFunction(arr) {
    // Returning the largest item in the list
    var max = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
    return max;
}

console.log(myFunction([1, 4]));
```